# Extend abstract generic class with abstract class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a base abstract class `public abstract class BaseModel <T extends BaseModel<T>>`. Normally, I extend this class with something like `public class OtherModel extends BaseModel<OtherModel>`. For some of my classes, I want to have an intermediate abstract class, such that A extends B extends BaseModel.

I'd like to be able to declare `public class EndModel extends MiddleModel<EndModel>`. The only way I've managed to get Eclipse to be happy is if I declare `MiddleModel` as `public abstract class MiddleModel<T extends BaseModel<T>> extends BaseModel<T>`, but this seems ugly, and now I have to add a type anywhere I declare a variable as `MiddleModel`, even if I don't actually care what type it is. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Nope. If you want `MiddleModel` to be generic then it needs to be generic. You can declare it as `MiddleModel<?>` if you don't care what the type is.

Comment: That's what I've been doing so far. I'd like to just be able to declare the type in `EndModel` and not have to worry about types with `MiddleModel`

Comment: @BoristheSpider if you throw that in an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add more functionality in *MiddleModel*, which depends on the generic type of it, declare it like this:

```
public abstract class BaseModel <T extends BaseModel<T>> {}

public abstract class MiddleModel <T extends MiddleModel<T>> extends BaseModel<T> {}

public class EndModel extends MiddleModel<EndModel> {}
```

Note that *EndModel* doesn't support that extensibility. It's a trade-off, because I don't want to write `new EndModel<EndModel>()` but rather `new EndModel()`.